# Honouring of AttributeUsage on derived attribute types

Tags: c#, inheritance, attributes, allowmultiple

Given the following, I would not expect the compiler to allow multiple attributes that are derived from the base attribute, given that is set to AllowMultiple=false.  In fact it compiles without a problem - what am I missing here?

```
using System;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property,AllowMultiple=false,Inherited=true)]
abstract class BaseAttribute : Attribute { }

sealed class DerivedAttributeA : BaseAttribute { }

sealed class DerivedAttributeB : BaseAttribute { }

    class Sample1
    {
        [DerivedAttributeA()]
        [DerivedAttributeB()]
        public string PropertyA{ get; set; } // allowed, concrete classes differ

        [DerivedAttributeA()]
        [DerivedAttributeA()]
        public string PropertyB { get; set; } // not allowed, concrete classes the same, honours AllowMultiple=false on BaseAttribute
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is simply that the `AllowMultiple` check only compares attributes of the same *actual* type (i.e. the concrete type instantiated) - and is perhaps best used with `sealed` attributes for this reason.

It will, for example, enforce the following (as an illegal duplicate), inheriting this from `BaseAttribute`:

```
[DerivedAttributeB()]
[DerivedAttributeB()]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

In short, I don't think you can do what you want here... (enforce no more than one instance *including subclasses* of `BaseAttribute` per property).

A similar example of this problem would be:

```
[Description("abc")]
[I18NDescriptionAttribute("abc")]
public string Name { get; set; }

class I18NDescriptionAttribute : DescriptionAttribute {
    public I18NDescriptionAttribute(string resxKey) : base(resxKey) { } 
}
```

The intent above is to provide a `[Description]` from resx at runtime (fully supported by `ComponentModel` etc) - but it **can't** stop you also adding a `[Description]`.

Comment: I feared that might be the case, thanks for the confirmation.